# Как называется в любой IDE полоска справа где идет нумерация строк?

Tags: ide, терминология

Как называется в любой IDE полоска справа где идет нумерация строк?

Я что-то отчасти подобное верстаю.. хочу узнать, чтоб обозвать его правильным классом.

Comment: Называйте так чтобы самому было всегда ясно что это такое. А так можете посмотреть исходники редакторов с открытым кодом.

Comment: Не знаю, как называется, но предлагаю LineCounter .

Comment: Слева, вроде, а не справа

Comment: За все IDE сказать не берусь, в Sublime Text она называется [**gutter**](http://www.sublimetext.ru/documentation/preferences/gutter), переводят как «канавка». В [**Intellj Idea**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31011858/5951529) и [**PyCharm**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17771339/5951529) тоже gutter. Вероятно, это и есть общеупотребительный термин — [**«The grey area on the left side of the Editor is called the Gutter»**](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/code-editor/window/gutter.html). Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных он и по-русски называется гаттер, старый  типографский термин для пробелов между колонками или между текстом и линией корешка. Значение слова- "канавка" - объясняет его происхождение. О, промежутки между марками  под разрез типографского листа так же называются гаттерами.или дорожками.

Comment: @Swift: спасибо за информацию! Было бы неплохо, если бы отразили её в ответе, а не комментарии.

Comment: я же не могу отметить лучший комментарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `gutter`

Спасибо большое за комментарии к вопросу, все доходчиво. но я не могу отметить комментарий лучшим.. Скопирую чтоб сделать вопрос решенным